# Extracting coordinates of polygons

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Hello I have a binary values images.

What is the best way to extract the coordinates of shapes with values of one's.

Thanks for ideas.

[image]

Comment: I would use OpenCV https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: you would basically need to sweep line by line and see when the pixels first and last changes... as mentioned use OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `skimage` library instead of going for OpenCV.

```
from skimage import measure
contours = measure.find_contours(im, 0.8)
```

`contours` returns an array of coordinates around those shapes with value of 1.

Check the documentation [HERE](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py) for more

Answer (score -1):

A simplified version is to use where to get the rows and columns then transpose if you want to.

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

np.where(a == 1)
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5], dtype=int64))

np.array(np.where(a == 1)).T
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 5]], dtype=int64)
```